# Pandas: how to fill null values matching the right types of that column?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

The [Dataframe.fillna method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) can fill null values with a default value.

But when we have both string and numeric type columns, how to fill the numeric-type null cells with number 0, and fill the string-type null cells with string "0" or "blank"?

EDIT:

The table contains thousands of mixed-type columns, so it is not feasible to fillna for each column manually.

Comment: I think you'd have to do separate `fillna` for each column.

Comment: According to the docs, you can pass a sequence of fill values, one per column

Comment: Why damm thumb down? Is this question irrelevant to stackoverflow community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take each column individually.

If the column contains type string

```
df.column.fillna('0',inplace = True)
```

If the column contains type int

```
df.column.fillna(0 ,inplace = True)
```

where the `inplace = True` just fills within the same dataframe